# Browser Specific HTML Possible?

Tags: internet-explorer, html, browser

Is there a way that I can have a different section of HTML code shown, based on the browser the user is viewing from?  For example:

Show this div for IE7:

```
<div id="ie7styles"><p>This is my IE 7 text</p></div>
```

Show this div for every other browser:

```
<div id="mystyles"><p>This is every other browsers text</p><img src="#"></div>
```

The reason why I want to do this is because I have a simple CSS parallax effect, but as `inherit` and `background-size` are not supported in IE7, I would like a default image to just be show if viewing from IE7, so there is not a gap.

Comment: Specifically for IE there are *conditional comments*. Google that.

Comment: You will get much better response if you explain *why* you're trying to do something; there's a good chance that there are other alternative solutions to your underlying problem which may be better than having browser-version-specific code, but we won't be able to offer those solutions if we don't know what the underlying problem is that you're trying to solve. Also, to avoid down-votes on questions you should include what you've tried so far and why it didn't work.

Comment: Okay, so the issue is lack of support for certain browser features, so perhaps [detecting whether those features exist](http://html5doctor.com/using-modernizr-to-detect-html5-features-and-provide-fallbacks/) would be a suitable solution instead of browser version detection? Or maybe finding a [polyfill script for the missing features](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use conditional comments

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <div>What ever you need tho show here</div>
<![endif]-->
```

everywhere on your html

See http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

for more different browsers. **It's is NOT just working for stylesheets**.

Another way is to user javascript. but I prefer this solution.

> UPDATE

I have no IE to test but now I think you updated the question and from what I see jQuery would have a good solution to change what you would like. It has to look for the elements you want to "change". I made an example to give you an idea of how it could work

http://jsfiddle.net/3PcxV/2/

Think about if you use this solution every ie7 user has to have javascript running. If not it want work! Thats why I would prefer the above solution. The other way is her you can change th code at only one place and just add the class to the elements need to be changed.

```
<div class="alwaysLikeThis">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
<div class="changeOnIe7">Show something else on IE7</div>
<div class="alwaysLikeThis changeOnIe7">Show something else on IE7</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) == 7) {
            alert("here");
           $( ".changeOnIe7" ).replaceWith( "<p class='newElement'>this is something else</p>" );
        }   
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Comment: You might want to elaborate on your answer - at the moment it really looks like something that should be a comment. You can do so by explaining its use, providing examples and their relevance to the question. Link only answers tend to be frowned upon as the links can stop working at a later date.